# Как отключить шпионскую программу

Tags: android, безопасность

Доброго всем вечера! 
Не могу избавиться от шпионской программе на смартфоне. Признаки:

1. Взломан Google аккаунт, взломщик сменил пароль, я не могу теперь войти в почту.
2. Среди администраторов устройства появился Удаленный доступ, я его отключила, но проблему это не решило.
3. Доктор веб показывает, что идут какие-то процессы с сайтов, которые я не посещала.
4. Когда включаю телефон, появляются странные надписи, типа "Города не добавлены". Ясно, что через мой телефон работают.
5. Когда я включила поиск wi-fi дома, то в списке доступных сетей (незапароленнных) значились две сети: default и ZyXEL, причем последняя начала ко мне без предупреждения подключаться.
6. Когда я попыталась отключить определение местоположения, то при клике на пункт меню, оно все время возвращало меня к главному экрану, не давая войти в настройки местоположения. Самое интересное, что я наутро этот пункт меню в телефоне на месте уже не нашла, также как и проверку dhcp соединения в Меню разработчика.
7. Доктор веб, ОС Андроид и Chrome оказывается передают у меня фоновые данные через wi-fi, что видно в Использовании данных. Хотя использование wi-fi у меня везде отключено.

Все программы получили права на все: на чтение и удаление данных, контроль над интернет соединением и пр. Телефон пару раз сделал мне селфи, когда я работала на нем, я его точно не делала, просто не делаю таких снимков.

8. На экране справа наверху появляется значок копирования, котоый блокирует экран.
9. По телефону стало очень плохо слышно. Мне жалуются, что по телефону нeвозможно дозвониться, хотя он лежит рядом включенный и заряженный.
10. На телефон стали постурать звонки со скрытых номеров, чего раньше не было.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне избавиться от фоновых процессов, которые контролируют мой телефон, как отсоединить ОС Андроид от сети wi-fi, и как защитить сеть от взлома. Антивирус не помог. Сброс к заводским настройкам помогает только на один день, потом идет звонок со странных номеров и все начинается сначала. С чего хотя бы начать, чтобы определить, откуда проблема.

Answer (score 2):

1. Сменить пароль к гугл аккаунту (если к нему привязан номер телефона или другой почтовый ящик, то это легко можно сделать).
2. Завести другой гугл аккаунт.
3. Вернуться к заводским настройкам.
4. Поменять прошивку (понадобится `root`).

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте! В данном случае я посоветую Вам сбросить все данные с устройства через настройки. Если не получается, сбрасывайте настройки через RecoveryMode

Comment: Это первое, что я сделала, отсоединила google account. Но помогает очень на короткое время, потом  телефон опять взламывается. Есть ли более серьезные средства?

Comment: Вирус мог проникнуть в систему, если имеются root права на устройстве. Если это так, то устройство нужно перепрошивать

Comment: @Tigra название, модель телефона?

Comment: Телефон samsung A5 2016. Рут прав на телефоне не должно быть. Доктор веб показывает, что даже при удалении мобильной точки доступа в настройках телефона и запрета доступа к интернету по мобильной сети и wi fi для chrome и системы все равно идут активные интернет соединения (синхронизация контактов, chrome и root). В Использовании данных не могу посмотреть Параметры приложения, это меню заблокировано. Вопрос: как отсоединить мое устройство от сети wi fi (все сделала уже для этого), как найти шпионскую прогу и отловить (в фоне) этот процесс?

Comment: К заводским настройкам уже возвращалась 3 раза, меняла прикрепленный гугл аккаунт, телефон все равно взламывается, нужна более серьезная защита с контролем за фоновыми процессами, программами, названия которых не отображаются в диспетчере задач и входящими соединениями.

Comment: Отцепите Samsung Account и поменяйте его тоже, если вы меняете Google Account и все равно заходят, это означает что заходят через Samsung account - там есть возможность удаленного доступа.

Comment: @Tigra помог ли совет Barmaley по смене Samsung Account или стоит дальше покапать?

Comment: Прошу прощения за поздний ответ, дома у меня мобильный интернет не работает, приходится выходить на улицу. Samsung  аккаунт я давно отцепила, в администраторах нашла удаленный доступ и удалила. Я могу сброситься к заводским настройкам, но по прибытии домой мне интернет взломают и заблокируют опять. Я думаю wireshark поставить и блокировать хакерские процессы. Сейчас сижу и в брандмауре доктор Веб с грустью наблюдаю за блокировкой своих процессов...

Comment: Копать нужно намного дальше отсоединения аккаунтов, по всему видно за мой телефон крепко взялись.

Comment: Причем интересно. Иногда я смотрю и вижу, что в брандмауре идут не мои процессы, а мои заморожены, а иногда есть только мои запросы и все они заморожены. Я не могу понять способ блокировки-шпионская прога блокирует изнутри или может работать аппаратный блокатор? Теперь дома интернета нет совсем и надо что-то делать, я ведь за него плачу и хотелось бы им пользоваться)